# При тестировании AJAX запросов JQuery загружается после старта тестов на Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, юнит-тесты, jasmine

У меня есть функция которая отправляет AJAX запрос на сервер

JS

```
function loadImage(e){

    var id = $('#idDomain').val();
    var nameHolder = $('#nameImgHolder').val();
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('file', e.files[0]);
    data.append('id', id);
    data.append('nameHolder', nameHolder);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/mr_generator/loadImageAjax/",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: data
        })
    .success(function (data) {
       addHistory(nameHolder, data["fileName"]);
       replaceSrc(data, nameHolder);
    });
}
```

И есть тест который должен проверить корреткность URL куда будет отправлен запрос

JS

```
it("should make an Ajax request to the correct URL", function () {
     spyOn($, "ajax");
     var file = {
        files: ['file.jpg']
     };
     loadImage(file);
     expect($.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]).toBe('/mr_generator/clearLastHistoryAjax/');
});
```

Но при запуске теста выдает следующую ошибку

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...) is undefined in ....
```

Я так понял, что у меня тесты запускаются раньше загрузки JQuery? Как это исправить?

Comment: Дождитесь полной загрузки DOM и затем запускайте текст. Оберните тест в обработчик события ready. $(function() {  тест  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Vitaliy Shevchenko за совет, но я сделал немного по-другому, я в функцию beforEach вынес вызов функции, в которой вызывается AJAX запрос (loadImage()), и обернул вызов в setInterval(), получился следующий тест

JS

```
describe('Clear history Ajax', function () {

    var configuration = {
        url: "/mr_generator/clearLastHistoryAjax/",
        remainingCallTime: 30000
    };
    var file = {
        files: ['file.jpg']
    };

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        var ajaxInterval = setInterval(function () {
            loadImage(file);
            done();
        }, 400);
    });

    //checking url of request
    it("should make an Ajax request to the correct URL", function () {
        spyOn($, "ajax");
        expect($.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]).toBe('/mr_generator/clearLastHistoryAjax/');
    });
 });
```